# I need to remove all invisible characters in python

Tags: python, string

i have a long text which i need to be as clean as possible.
I have collapsed multiple spaces in one space only. I have removed \n and \t. I stripped the resulting string.

I then found characters like \u2003 and \u2019
What are these? How do I make sure that in my text I will have removed all  special characters?

Besides the \n \t and the \u2003, should I  check for more characters to remove?
I am using python 3.6

Comment: Don't filter out characters. You **will** miss some. Whitelist the ones you want to accept.

Comment: What are you using the text for?

Comment: I am using it in a neural network (LTSM) and I am concerned that these characters may introduce distortions. @spectras: what do you mean “whitelist the ones I want to accept”. I get the concept but how do I do it?

Comment: Basically the way Mike's answer below does it, except you put your own list instead of the `\W`. For instance, `[^\w,:;=-]+`. The `[]` enclose the set, `^` as first char within means *"negate the set"*, then you simply list what you want to keep. Most chars stand for themselves, `\w` means letters, hyphen must come last… grab python's `re` module documentation for an exhaustive rule list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
# string contains the \u2003 character
string = u'This is a   test string ’'
# this regex will replace all special characters with a space
re.sub('\W+',' ',string).strip()
```

Result

```
'This is a test string'
```

If you want to preserve ascii special characters:

```
re.sub('[^!-~]+',' ',string).strip()
```

This regex reads: select [not characters 34-126] one or more times, where characters 34-126 are the visible range of ascii.

In regex , the `^` says not and the `-` indicates a range. Looking at an ascii table, 32 is `space` and all characters below are either a button interrupt or another form of white space like `tab` and `newline`. Character 33 is the `!` mark and the last displayable character in ascii is 126 or `~`.

Comment: Hi Mike, the problem is that the solution you suggested gets rid of non printable characters but also of  punctuaction. "This isn't a book" becomes "this isn t a book"

Comment: Hi Mike, it works indeed!!! It works great. I just don't understand "why" it works. I know what [^ -~] is. But i do not understand what changes with exclamation mark.

Comment: Thanks for helping Mike!

Comment: I’ve added a little more to my answer for you.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot Mike

Comment: Thank you. this is great when the text is English only. It will however remove text that is not English.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mike Peder, this solution worked for me. However I had to do it for both sides of the comparison

```
if((re.sub('[^!-~]+',' ',date).strip())==(re.sub('[^!-~]+',' ',calendarData[i]).strip())):
```